# How do modified condition operators work? SQL - ALL and ANY

Tags: sql

Lets say I have a table A with attribute numbers that looks like this.

A
numbers
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

What will this query return? How is the 5 getting compared?

```
SELECT numbers
FROM A
WHERE 5 > ALL (SELECT numbers FROM a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ALL` statement requires that ALL of the results returned by your subquery

`(SELECT numbers FROM A)`

to respect the condition (to be smaller than 5), otherwise the condition is not met and no results are returned.

In your case, there are numbers returned by the subquery, `SELECT numbers FROM a`, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 which are greater than 5, thus not ALL numbers respect the condition, so the condition is evaluated to FALSE, and no rows are returned.

**Update:**

Based on your comments I added details to my answer:

The statement using **ALL** condition should be read as:

"If ALL of the numbers returned by `(SELECT numbers FROM A)` are smaller than 5, then return the numbers selected by your `MAIN SELECT`."

The statement using **ANY** condition should be read as:

"If ANY of the numbers returned by `(SELECT numbers FROM A)` are smaller than 5, then return the numbers selected by your `MAIN SELECT`."

You can run the query in this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b99da/8)** to see how the results change, just replace ANY with ALL and see the difference.

Comment: So if I were to do 5 > ANY, would I just get back 6 7 8 9 10?

Comment: @user1773070 If you were to do `ANY`, then it would return ALL of the numbers, 1 to 10. `ANY` condition should be read as: "if ANY of the numbers in this SELECT statement are smaller than 5, then return ALL of the numbers".

Answer (score 1):

It will return an empty resultset (no rows).

The WHERE clause is evaluated for each row in the table A [first instance].
The WHERE clause tests whether 5 is greater than EACH row in table A [second instance].
It is not (there are several rows where the value is greater than 5) so the WHERE clause is always false.
Therefore no rows from table A [first instance] pass the query, therefore no rows are returned.